# Kill all "helpful" new network management things on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, dhcp

I've just upgraded a Ubuntu 16.04 machine to Ubuntu 18.04 because of EOL.

I'd forgotten just how many "helpful" network things are forced onto you in Ubuntu 18.04 that were not there or optional in Ubuntu 16.04:

- NetworkManager (uninstalling now removes some critical Gnome components)
- systemd-resolved
- netplan

Searching finds various ways to get rid of each one individually, but each article seems to assume you want to keep the other parts (e.g. most search results for removing "systemd-resolved" are talking about making changes to NetworkManager to make it work with the removal of systemd-resolved)

Is there a simple method to get rid of all of this stuff that I do not need, and to just go back to a simple system, with the interfaces configured through /etc/network/interfaces. As a slight complication, I'm configuring the network using DHCP (via a static allocation from my DHCP server), and want to be able to get back to what worked in Ubuntu 16.04 (and also works fine in Debian 9 and Debian 10), which is to have the DHCP client populating /etc/resolv.conf properly without all these other unnecessary packages.

Surely this is possible on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Instead of destroying your upgraded system by uninstalling pieces of it, why not learn why those pieces are there, and how to use them? Nobody drives a brand new car knowing all of the features that it has. That comes over time.

Comment: I doubt that there is anything simpler than Network Manager; click, connect and done. I also doubt that putting a single barrel carburetor on a 2021 BMW will make it a better car.

Comment: You are chasing a false goal, taking your system back towards the old way, the old, unsupported way, for unspecified "reasons", probably because you tripped over EOL, probably because you ignored EOL. Learn to use the new tools, read the change logs `apt changelog packagename`. Search, both here on AskUbuntu and on the internet.

Comment: I'm sure for some people, all the new network stuff is really useful. But in my experience, the vast majority of Linux systems are servers that sit on a single network all their lives, usually with a single fixed IP address. All the clever stuff that Network Manager and systemd-resolved are designed to address are simply not something I encounter in my day to day usage of Linux. There is an old adage "if it isn't broke, don't fix it", and for me (and from Internet searching many others), configuring the networking using the /etc/network/interfaces file is definitely in that category

Comment: I can learn a new thing, but still keep the old thing. OldGuy says Early releases of AIX had a sysadmin GUI that covered about 80% of all sysadmin tasks. Which 80%? Undocumented.